# viewer error when running the stokesCavity.py example

Tags: python, fipy

Running Manjaro stable with python-3.9 and python-fipy-3.4.2.1-1.

Just got started with FiPy, ultimately interested in writing single and two-phase flow code. Naturally I tried to run `examples/flow/stokesCavity.py` (stripped down from all rst text) with: `python stokesCavity.py` and it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zbinkz/HGST/Projects/Python/fipy/examples/flow/stokesCavity.py", line 117, in <module>
    viewer = Viewer(vars=(pressure, xVelocity, yVelocity, velocity),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fipy/viewers/__init__.py", line 130, in Viewer
    raise ImportError("Failed to import a viewer: %s" % str(errors))
ImportError: Failed to import a viewer: ["matplotlib: True is not a valid value for orientation; supported values are None, 'vertical', 'horizontal'", "mayavi: No module named 'enthought'"]
```

I tinkered with different values for `FIPY_VIEWER` in the `viewer` command at line 117 reported above but still get the same error. At this very early stage with FiPy I'm clueless, anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this line](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/blob/f491c876aa9a3c58eb873d042a666eed7705c8d6/examples/flow/stokesCavity.py#L221), change

```py
...     viewer = Viewer(vars=(pressure, xVelocity, yVelocity, velocity),
...                xmin=0., xmax=1., ymin=0., ymax=1., colorbar=True)
```

to

```py
...     viewer = Viewer(vars=(pressure, xVelocity, yVelocity, velocity),
...                xmin=0., xmax=1., ymin=0., ymax=1., colorbar='vertical')
```

I've filed a [ticket](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/828) to correct this.